# Adding months to a date and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to add X month to a date taken from my database

```
$sql_batch = "SELECT * FROM mgm_subscription WHERE status = '1'"
$query_batch = mysql_query($sql_batch);
$row_batch = mysql_fetch_array($query_batch);

$addMonth = 3;
$startDate = $row_batch['start_month'];
$endDate = strtotime('+'.$addMonth.' month', $startMonth);  // add number of days from form
$endDate = date('m/d/y H:i:s', $endDate );  

$sql_date = "INSERT INTO user_subscription (user_id, start_month, end_month, sub_status) VALUES ('".$usercode2."','".$startDate."','".$endDate."', '')";
$query_date = mysql_query($sql_date);
```

NULL was inserted into the end_month. 
start_month and end_month is DATE type in the mysql

how do i fix this? tq.

Comment: Is $startMonth a string or numeric value?

Comment: if data type is `date` , then from your example you are trying to insert `datetime` , Also valid mysql datetime format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: i inserted the value of $end_month into a varchar data type field. and it inputs 04/01/70 01:33:34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, your `$endDate` should be

```
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate.' +'.$addMonth.' months'));
```

So this will equate to:

```
$endDate = $startDate + 3 months /* in Y-m-d format */
```

EDIT: Just saw that your column datatype is `Date`. This would mean that you can't store timestamp in your date. It has to be `Y-m-d` format only as that is the valid mysql format supported.

Answer (score 0):

You insert $endMonth a value(number of days from form) then you try to replace it ($endMonth) and you call back your replaced variable..

> $endMonth = strtotime('+'.$addMonth.' month', $startMonth);  // add number of days from form
>       $endMonth = date('m/d/y H:i:s', $endMonth);

It will return null value.. My suggestion, try to put other variable to prevent duplicate value or missing data

Comment: even i use a different var, it still inserts NULL inside my db. I think the problem is on the format of the value sent to the db.

Comment: You change it to $endDate but $endMonth in $endDate = date('m/d/y H:i:s', $endMonth); still did't have a value

Comment: i change it. and it still the same, it inserted 04/01/70 01:33:34 when i put it in a varchar field

Comment: if your format of date is 5/1/2014 12:00:00 AM.. so i suggest you change to $endMonth = strtotime('+'.$addMonth.' month', $startMonth); $endDate = date('n/j/Y H:i:s', $endMonth);

Answer (score 0):

You only mention adding X months. Maybe I misunderstood your question, but if *all you care about is the month*, I would do the following:

```
if ($startMonth === 'January') {
    $monthNumber = 1;
} else if ($startMonth === 'February') {
    $monthNumber = 2;
} //Up to November then finish with {
else {
    $monthNumber = 12;//December
}

$newMonthNumber = $monthNumber + $addMonth;

if ($newMonthNumber % 12 == 1) {
    $endMonth = 'January';
} else if ($newMonthNumber % 12 == 1) {
    $endMonth = 'February';
} //Up to November then finish with {
  else {
    $endMonth = 'December';
}

$sql_date = "INSERT INTO user_subscription (user_id, start_month, end_month, sub_status) VALUES ('".$usercode2."','".$startMonth."','".$endMonth."', '')";
$query_date = mysql_query($sql_date);
```

Comment: tq for replying, but i think u misunderstood the problem, adding the month is determined for $addMonth. In this case is 3, so i need to add 3 months from the $startMonth date and insert it into the DB

Comment: What is inserted into the database? A month only, or a date? The variable names $endMonth and $startMonth suggest months and not dates.

Comment: sorry, it's a full date. like this 5/1/2014 12:00:00 AM .. sorry for the bad programing. i change it already to avoid confusions